# Persisting values across re-execution of release pipeline in Azure DeOops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am configuring a release pipeline in Azure DevOps and I want the variables that get generated along the tasks to persist across re-execution of the same release. I wanted to know if that is possible.
The main goal is to create a pipeline that i can redeploy in case of a failure, if for example I have a release pipeline with 30 tasks, I would want handle skipping the tasks that got completed, but once I reach the relevant task, I need the persisted variable values.

I have looked online and I see it isn't possible to persist variables across phases, but does that also mean it cannot be persisted in the same release pipeline if I redeploy it?

From searching stack exchange and google I got to the following GitHub issue on the subject, I just wasn't sure if it also affects my own situation in the same way.

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that by default unless I interpret you wrong. When redeploying the same release pipeline variables values you define (in the pipeline) do not change.

Calculated values are not persisted

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for not being a bit more clear, I do mean variables that are calculated along inside the tasks themselves. I have edited my question

Comment: still not possible, only works for builds, but not for reexecution. with reexecution they will get recalculated... you can add a script task to update the value of the variable in the release definition from inside the release. again this would get executed on every run. so I really do not understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to create an option for a release pipeline to resume from the point it had an error. If i have 30 tasks and task 27 failed, i would like to resume from it. The release pipeline will start from the 1st task but i am handling the functionality of skipping the done steps, i just want to have the consecutive tasks the values i caclulcated originally.

Comment: technically you could query the api and figure out where the pipeline failed on the previous run

Comment: That would help me resume on the failed step but not keep the variables (unless i keep them externally in a file or some azure storage account)

Comment: well, you cant really solve this problem without some external storage, because ADO doesnt support this